# Is there any pseudoprime, $p$ such that $p\not\equiv\pm{1\bmod{18}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, primality-test

### Little Explanation

here is a recurrence relation defined by $d_n = 3d_{n - 2} - d_{n - 3}$ where $d_1=0, d_2 = 1$ and $d_3 = 2$. this recurrence relation can be used to test if number $p$ is prime. and $p$ is prime if and only if $d_p, d_{p+1}$ and $d_{p+2}$ are either $\{1, 2, 3\}$, $\{2, 1, 1\}$ or $\{-3, -3, -4\}$ all of these $\bmod{p}$. this test is deterministic for all number, $n$ such that $n\not\equiv\pm{1}\bmod{18}$, since all pseudoprimes are of this form, why? this seuence is periodic and the period of all prime numbers that are congruent to $\pm{1}\bmod{18}$ is $(p - 1)\times{k}$ where $k$ is less than or equal to $1$. this kind of period that depend on $p - 1$ cause periodic collision resulting to pseudoprimes. and all pseudoprimes have all of its prime factors of form $\pm{1}\bmod{18}$ but i havent found any pseudoprime of congruent to $-1\bmod 18$ but i suspect they exist.

All prime numbers $p$ that are not congruent to $\pm1\bmod 18$ have periods of form ${2(p^2 + p + 1)\dot{k^{-1}}}$, these periods explodes to very big number and this avoids periodic collision that may result to pseudoprimes.

Comment: Did you concoct this relation, or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294521/is-there-any-pseudoprime-p-such-that-p-not-equiv-pm1-bmod18 without notification to either site. How rude!

Comment: This is my own relation... i have posted it to mathoverflow and there were no response that is why i decided to post here again

Comment: Am very sorry Gerry Myerson i forgot to delete on one site

Answer (score 2):

If you want to think about pseudoprimes with respect to third-order recurrence sequences, a good place to start is Adams and Shanks' 1982 paper on Perrin pseudoprimes. I suspect you will find that all of your examples are what they call "S-pseudoprimes". There are probably infinitely many "Q-pseudoprimes", but nobody has found one yet.

Comment: But out of these two kind of pseudoprimes$\bmod p$... i think there is no pseudoprime. And this test is deterministic for all other numbers. Because i have been studying alot of recurrence relations and this have special properties among all others

Comment: When I say there are "probably" infinitely many Q-pseudoprimes, I mean there is a 1984 heuristic due to Pomerance (https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/dopo.pdf) that can be adapted to any case where the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence relation splits into at most quadratic factors (the "Q" case). I see no reason the heuristic fails for this sequence.

Comment: First, i havent said there is no psedoprimes. There are,  but all of them exist in two đifferent straight lines that are equivalent to 1 or -1 modulo 18.  I have a list of all pseudoprimes from 1 to 120M , all of these are $1\pmod18$ no counter example of $-1\bmod18$, am not sure if they dont exist.

Comment: Am very sure from studies i have conducted in this recurrence relation that they or you will never ever find any pseudoprime out of these two lines and this will never happen in a million years

Comment: Am writing paper about this discovery